# Trouble updating/setting the image in a UIImageView

Tags: uiimageview, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to call a UIImagePickerController and use the info that it gets to update a UIImageView. I can't get the UIImage from the info to the UIImageView.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage* originalImage = nil;
    originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [myImage setImage:originalImage]; //also tried myImage.image = originalImage

    NSLog(@"originalImage: %@\n", originalImage);
    NSLog(@"userImage.image: %@\n", myImage.image);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

When I run this code the UIImageView stays blank.
I get a console output of:

```
originalImage: <UIImage: 0x80e0f90>
userImage.image: (null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myImage` is null, so any call on it has no effect, something should be assigned to it beforehand (`myImage = ...` or `self.myImage = ...`)